# Change CSS only for single component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a project in angular, where I need to change the CSS class only for the current component. I am doing something like this:

```
selector: 'app-container',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styles: [
  `.cd1-overe{
    top: auto !important;
  }
  .cd1r .cd2{
    top: 7rem !important;
  }`
],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

By doing this, the CSS is updated for all of the components, because this change is applied to global CSS.

Comment: Can you not give the component a different class, which holds the different CSS?

Comment: Class is used globally and applied dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the encapsulation mode to `None`. With this and with the `!important` modifier the component css rules are overriding the global css rules.

Instead of this set the encapsulation mode to `Emulated` or just delete it (because `Emulated` is the default). And in this case you won't need the `!important` modifier also.

Answer (score 1):

To change the CSS class only for the current component, use component-specific styles. By default, Angular encapsulates the styles within the component's styles array, ensuring they do not affect other components.

Try the following steps to do it:

Remove the encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None` line from your component decorator. This will revert to the default encapsulation mode, which is `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`.

Define your component with component-specific styles just like below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [
    `
    .cd1-overe {
      top: auto !important;
    }
    
    .cd1r .cd2 {
      top: 7rem !important;
    }
    `
  ]
})
```

By using this, the styles you define will only apply to the HTML elements within the `app-container` component, and won't affect other components in your Angular application.

You may not have to use the `!important` flag if you are not using any additional class or inline styles on the HTML side.